# Reading an INI file and setting them as global variables in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that does a bunch f things already and been trying to expand it to get some data from an ini file.

The ini file for example looks like this

```
[Settings1]
Text=Text
Text1=Text
Text2=Text

[Settings2]
Text=Text
Text1=Text
Text2=Text
```

I have figured out a way to get the section I require with the following batch

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "file=settings.ini"
set "section=[Settings1]"

set flag=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%# in ("%file%") do (
    set line=%%#
    ::trim
    for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("!line!") do set "line=%%a"
    set f=!line:~0,1!
    if "!f!" neq ";" (
        if !flag! equ 1 (
            ::for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("!line!") do (
            for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("%%#") do (
                set "!section!.%%a=%%b"

            )
        )

        if "!f!" equ "[" (
            if "!line!" equ "%section%" (
                set flag=1
            ) else (
                set flag=0
            )
        )       
    )
)

set %section%
```

This then outputs the following

```
Settings1.Text=Text
Settings1.Text1=Text
Settings1.Text2=Text
```

What I want to be able to do but cannot work out how to do is to take in each of these outputs and assign the value so just the 'Text' after the equals sign to its own variable that can then be recalled later in my script

Comment: Not sure, what your problem is. You already have the values in separate variables: `echo %[Settings1].Text1%`

Comment: instead of `set section` at the bottom, try independently echoing each. i.e `echo %[Settings1].Text%`, `echo %[Settings1].Text1%` and `echo %[Settings1].Text2%`

Comment: So yes this works exactly how I want it too - the issue is Settings1 is  hardcoded I atm am setting that with a variable named section.

Comment: Why are you adding the section name to each and every line parsed within the known section? If you don't want it, don't add it. Surely you just want to be able to use, `%Text%`, `%Text1%`, and `%Text2%` or `!Text!`, `!Text1!`, and `!Text2!`, and get the value that was assigned under whichever section you initially defined for `%section%`.

Comment: @Compo because I don't know how to do that, and is why I am here asking for help.

Comment: Remove, `!section!.` from `set "!section!.%%a=%%b` would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the below example. I used your existing code, even though it can be improved. You can see how I utilized the `for /l` loop to give you an idea of what can be done. You can shape this to fit your desired result. You can consider the same solution for different sections as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=settings.ini"
set "section=[Settings1]"
set num=0
set flag=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%# in ("%file%") do (
    set line=%%#
    ::trim
    for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("!line!") do set "line=%%a"
    set f=!line:~0,1!
    if "!f!" neq ";" (
        if !flag! equ 1 (
            ::for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("!line!") do (
            for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("%%#") do (
                set "!section!.%%a=%%b"
                set /a num+=1

            )
        )

        if "!f!" equ "[" (
            if "!line!" equ "%section%" (
                set flag=1
            ) else (
                set flag=0
            )
        )       
    )
)

for /l %%a in (0,1,%num%) do (
  if %%a equ 0 (
     if defined [Settings1].Text echo(%[Settings1].Text%
   ) else (
     if defined [Settings1].Text%%a echo(![Settings1].Text%%a!
  )
)
```

Comment: This does work and I been able to do this. However I do not want to use settings1 as hardcoded atm it is set using a variable named %section% this is because in the live script it takes a user input and populats section with that

Comment: Yes. That is why I said you can use a simlar loop to do each section as well. No hard coding.